# Can we use tedious-connection-pool for type 'azure-active-directory-msi-app-service' to connect Azure-AD SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, azure-managed-identity, tedious

While trying with the connection config from Microsoft Docs, it is throwing an error

> Login failed for user ''**'

which made me think, tedious-connection-pool only works for username/password combination.

```
// Use Azure App Service Managed Identity to connect to the SQL database
var ConnectionPool = require('tedious-connection-pool');
var Request = require('tedious').Request;

var poolConfig = {
    min: 2,
    max: 4,
    log: true
};

var connectionConfig = {
        server: _this.config.sqlServer,
        authentication: {
            type: 'azure-active-directory-msi-app-service',
            options: {
              clientId: <<clientID>>,
            }
        },
        options: {
            database: <<database>>,
            serverName: <<serverName>>,
            encrypt: true,
            port: 1433
        }
    };

//create the pool
var pool = new ConnectionPool(poolConfig, connectionConfig);

pool.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});

//acquire a connection
pool.acquire(function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
    }

    //use the connection as normal
    var request = new Request('select * from Users', function(err, rowCount) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }

        console.log('rowCount: ' + rowCount);

        //release the connection back to the pool when finished
        connection.release();
    });

    request.on('row', function(columns) {
        console.log('value: ' + columns[0].value);
    });

    connection.execSql(request);
});
```

If anyone has tried this and made this work, please help with a working example.

Thanks.

Comment: Does our managed identity has been granted permission to the target database? Also i dont think you need to specify the clientid if you re using the system assigned identity of the webapp.

Comment: the clientId might has been extra thing, but yes permission has been added to the db, And I am able to connect using tedious. But trying with 'tedious-connection-pool' is not working.

Comment: looking at github, the repo doesnt seem to be maintained: https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious-connection-pool/issues/61.

Comment: Didn't you already ask this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69562153/have-anyone-successfully-connected-sql-server-through-aad-managed-identity-for

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid - It was a generic qn about tedious connection. Now I am trying to use tedious-connection-pool after successful connection using tedious.

Comment: If you got it to work. _please_ add an answer to your original question and accept. It will help many others.